# android- databinding -add text after data biding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to add some custom text after getting data from data binding

this is my code:

```
 android:text="@{model.numCards}"
```

it returns the value and set it to my view correctly but I need to add some more text after that

For example, the above code return 5 and I want it to add "number of cards" after 5

How can I do so ?

Comment: use two way binding "@={model.numCards}"..

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
android:text="@{model.numCards + ' ' + @string/num_of_cards}"
```